# Разделить html фрагмент кода на две части

Tags: php

Необходимо разделить html фрагмент кода на две части, при этом теги не должны обрезаться

```
<p>Какой то текст</p><span>Еще текст</span><span>Еще один текст</span>
```

Должно быть разбито на

```
 $var1 = "<p>Какой то текст</p>";
 $var2 = "<span>Еще текст</span><span>Еще один текст</span>";
```

Как не должно быть

```
$var1 = "<p>Какой то текст</p><span>Еще";
$var2 = "текст</span><span>Еще один текст</span>";
```

Желательно указывать какого размера будет первая часть разбитого текста

Comment: любой html парсер и бейте насколько угодно частей

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```php
<?php
$partsCount = 2;
$text = "<p>Какой то текст</p><span>Еще текст</span><span>Еще один текст</span>";
$parts = explode("><",$text, $partsCount);
for($i = 0; $i < count( $parts ); $i++ ) {
    if ( ($i+1) %2 != 0  ) {
        echo $parts[$i].">\n";
    } else {
        echo "<".$parts[$i]."\n";
    }
}
```